# Angular 2 Second Component Not Working?

Tags: javascript, angular

Ok, so my app currently has one module, which has two components, one is a gallery, which I bootstrap to start my app. The other is, or will be my menu system, however my A2 app seems to not render/run the component.

Module:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MenuComponent } from '../components/menu';
import { GalleryComponent }  from '../components/gallery';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ GalleryComponent, MenuComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ GalleryComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Menu:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: '[data-menu]',
  template: `<div></div>`
})

export class MenuComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('test 99 - const.');
  }
}
```

So my gallery component is fine, that works without any issues. However the very simple test Menu component I setup to test, does not seem to do anything. If I bootstrap the component, it runs the console.log. So what the hell am I doing wrong?

I have been on the A2.io site and look other again and again some of the test examples they have, but still cant see why this is not working?

Please help.

**EDIT**

I should have said that this A2 app is running within a Symfony 2, which is what I built the Json API for the gallery with.

So I have a Twig template (apart of Symfony) load the section tag with my data sector for my gallery, like so:

home.html.twig:

```
<main>
    <div id="PublicGallery">

        <section data-my-app>// Loading //</section> <- this loads my gallery without any issues!

    </div>
</main>
```

Above this I was going to but my nav tag, but I have not done that let, as I can not get the second A2 component to even console log?

Comment: Show us how you are using the gallery and the menu, I guess that you are adding them to your app.component.html, right? have you tried to use another selector for your menu? like just "my-app-menu", just to double check if the template compiler is doing something weird there.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for me to answer the question.  A given template can display n number of components but it seems like you just have two disjointed components that aren't tied together in any way. Can you give us some more information?  Show us the other component and templates for example?

Comment: @abszero please look at my edit, I hope thats what your looking for?

Comment: @C0ol_Cod3r, please consider set up a plunkr if possible. https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Comment: @Timathon - I dont see how that would help? I can, but as I have said in the question, the Gallery is being built by a Symfony 2 JSON API, which I could not re-build with plunker! So whatever I do on it, would not be completely the same. I am also using webpack to create a bundle file, rahter than use System JS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience working with Twig or Symfony (or bootstrapping without SystemJS for that matter) so I can't speak specifically about what you need to do within them to make this work.  That being said, a few things do jump out at me.

> So my gallery component is fine, that works without any issues. However the very simple test Menu component I setup to test, does not seem to do anything.

I don't see anywhere in the code you have provided where you are actually tying these two components together in a template.

> Ok, so my app currently has one module, which has two components, one is a gallery, which I bootstrap to start my app

What is likely happening is that the component you are bootstrapping is not tying in the other component. The snippets below are from an application that I am currently working on that you should be able to adapt to your needs. I have written this at a very basic level since I don't know how familiar you are with Angular2.

**file: index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <base href="/">
    <title>Some App</title>

    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ngApp></ngApp>
</body>
</html>
```

Since you aren't using SystemJS you can ignore that bit, but what is really important here are the `ngApp` tags. Think of these tags as the entry point into the rest of your application.  The following component will use these tags as a 'marker' on where to place its output.

**file: app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngApp',
    templateUrl: './app.template.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

This is really just boilerplate code and not much of interest, but notice that **ngApp**  is the selector for this component.  This is the first part in tying your application to your entry point.  Next is the template that this component will use.

**file: app.template.html**

```
<nav>
    <data-menu></data-menu>
</nav>
<gallery-component></gallery-component>
```

This is straightforward, but important.  The `data-menu` and `gallery-component` tags are where the two components you have already written are going to be displayed, but you need to make a modification to each of your components first.  In your gallery set the selector to: `selector: 'gallery-component'` and in your menu set the selector to `selector: 'data-menu'`  Next we need to setup the module.

**file: app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MenuComponent } from '../components/menu';
import { GalleryComponent }  from '../components/gallery';
import { AppComponent }  from '../components/app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, GalleryComponent, MenuComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Notice here that we include the AppComponent and that it is the component that we are bootstrapping.  The last thing is to make sure our main file is in order.

**file: main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

If you run the app at this point it should display a browser window with your menu component stacked on top of your gallery.

**A few parting thoughts / notes**

- You obviously don't need to use `templateUrl` and can instead use `template` if you prefer, but I don't like having templates baked directly into the component code.
- The much shorter answer to your question is simply that if you modify the template of your menu control to be something like `template: <div><gallery></gallery></div>` assuming that you bootstrap the menu and the gallery has a `selector` value of `'gallery'` it should display.  That isn't really useful though because that tightly couples the menu component to the galley component.
- Speaking of tight coupling, you will notice that both your menu and gallery components are now tightly coupled to the app component.  That is not terribly useful either.  Instead app.component should probably be setup with a `router-outlet` so that different components can be loaded on the page when menu options are clicked.  You can read about routing and navigation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

If you have any questions or if I haven't made something clear, please let me know.

Comment: Many many thanks - I sort of got it working just before reading for very detailed answer. I am not sure I like the process in which A2 is working, seems ponitless to me - that you need a Parent component, to load all the child componets that you want to boot. I got my code to work, once I added the tag to my bootstraped component and not in my Twig template - I see why. Is it just me for having the components work in this way, seem a little odd? But using the Parent Component as the Router wrapper seems like a good idea, I look into doing that! Many thanks

Comment: @C0ol_Cod3r I don't necessarily think it is odd, it is just a different way of thinking about things.  Any given web page is just a container for text and various components that make up the site. In my example above, while index.html is the actual page, app.component (specifically its template) is the main container for all of the things that would go on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you will need this in your GalleryComponent Template

```
<div data-menu></div>
```

Without looking at your GalleryComponent. I can't really tell what happening here.

Comment: Why would I need that? A) I dont want the Gallery Component to render anything apart from the gallery B) right now the second component is only console loging, so why do I need to add the data-menu? - But I have just added a nav tag to the Twig template with the data-menu attr, and it did not change anything!